# Is it possible to pre-assign values to decision variables in CPLEX OPL

Tags: websphere, cplex, opl

I have a large number of variables ( both Binary and Continuous). Therefore I have determined a logic to assign some variables set to 0 so that they do not become part of the optimisation process.

For example I have a binary decision variable y[b][t]:
where b varies from 1 to 100
and t from 1 to 5.

I could determine using some logic that y[20][2] onwards to y[100][2] would be 0. I want to assign the fixed value of 0 to these variables y[20][2] onwards to y[100][2] thereby reducing the number of variables in my optimisation problem. While y is a binary decision variable I have other continuous variable as well which I would like to similarly set to 0 in advance.

Is there a way how this can be achieved ? I haven't used Python with CPEX but hear that this can be probably be achieved by setting a lower and upper bound of the variables. Is there a similar method in OPL.

----Added 13th Aug
May be I was not very clear or I could not understand the solution suggested.

What I wanted is say I have the following decision variable Xbmt ...(I have a few of them)

Originally declared as :

dvar float+ Xbmt[PitBlocks][Plants][TimePeriods];

But for some of the PitBlocks and some time periods I want to define this decision variable as 0. Those time periods for which I want to set the decision variable as 0 are defined in a tuple nullVariables. It has block id same as PitBlocks, and it has time_period same as TimePeriod. Hence I want something like below. But I cannot declare the decision variable twice. I need it 0 only for those ids in the nullVariable set.

```
dvar float+ Xbmt[NullVariablesSet.block_id][Plants][NullVariablesSet.time_period] in 0..0;
```

---

How can this be achieved where some of Xbmt remain as decision variables where as some are removed by setting as 0

Answer (score 0):

see https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoopreassign.mod

within

[Making Decision Optimization Simple](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/)

```
int nbKids=300;

{int} seats={40,30}; // how many seats, {} means this is a set
float costBus[seats]=[500,400];

// Now let s see how preassign some decision variables
// Suppose we know that we have exactly 6 buses 40 seats

{int} preassignedseats={40};
int preassignedvalues[preassignedseats]=[6];

     
dvar int+ nbBus[s in seats] 
in 
((s in preassignedseats)?preassignedvalues[s]:0) 
.. 
((s in preassignedseats)?preassignedvalues[s]:maxint);

minimize sum(b in seats) costBus[b]*nbBus[b];
     
subject to
{
    sum(b in seats) b*nbBus[b]>=nbKids;
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, sorry for my late response, I have been trying various ways of achieving this but failed. I have added some more explanation of what I want to achieve. If you can please suggest on that basis.